# unable to read cache object from Zend registry

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

In bootstrap I am registering cache obj

```
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core','File',$frontendOptions,$backendOptions);
Zend_Registry::set('cache',$cache);
```

When I try to retrieve in model class ,It return the object but I am not able to get the list of function related to cache in my IDE.I was thinking atleast public method will get listed..

```
$this->_cache->load return false !
```

can you please help whats could possibly be wrong?.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What is it?

```
$this->_cache->load return false !
```

You can retrieve registry element from Model like this:

```
$cache = Zend_Registry::get('cache');
```

Comment: $this->_cache = Zend_registry::get('cache'); _cache is class variable in my class So when I use $this->_cache->load('key') it doesn't return anything

Comment: Please provide more info: how you set cache value, backend and frontend options.